# Why same object passes to lambda when applied in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, anonymous-class

I've a list of objects as `Collection<Cashflow> cashflows = cashflowDao.findAll();`. I then iterate over the list in a for loop and apply some action based on condition.

```
for(Cashflow cashflow: cashflows) {
          
            Condition condition = ruleService.getSTPCondition(cashflow, "NON-STP", "Counterparty STP Rule");
            Rule stpRules = getRule(cashflowDao, cashflow, condition);
            rules.register(stpRules);
            rulesEngine.fire(rules, facts);
        }
```

The `getRule()` implementation is:

```
private Rule getRule(CashflowDao cashflowDao, Cashflow cashflow, Condition condition) {
        System.out.println("Cashflow to evaluate:" + cashflow.getId()); //The cashflow id is unique.
        return new RuleBuilder().when(condition).then(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Facts facts) throws Exception {
                //The cashflow is the same old/first cashflow object in the list gets passed here.
                System.out.println("Cashflow Id to Load: " + cashflow.getId());
            }
        }).build();
}
```

In the `execute()` method the **first cashflow** in the list is always passed no matter what the current value of the object is. How can I pass the unique instance of cashflow object to `execute()`? If I have three cashflows with ids 97,98,99, the output is:

```
Cashflow to evaluate:97
Cashflow Id to Load: 97
Cashflow to evaluate:98
Cashflow Id to Load: 97
Cashflow to evaluate:99
Cashflow Id to Load: 97
```

Comment: can you explain where is the lambda use of this code

Comment: How is the program currently behaving? Is getRule invoked n times and always with the same cashflow object?
What is System.out.println("Cashflow to evaluate:" + cashflow.getId()); printing? Is is here will correct?

Comment: ```getRule()``` can be simplified to lambda as ```return new RuleBuilder()
                        .when(condition).then(action -> {
                            System.out.println("Cashflow to evaluate:" + cashflow.getId());
                            cashflowDao.applySTPRule(cashflow, "Cashflow marked as NON-STP.");
                        }).build();```

Comment: There is no issue with lambda or anonymous inner class. Please check the cashflow instance in cashflows collection. There could be issue on collocation or applySTPRule method

Comment: Can you please show applySTPRule method?

Comment: @Mohammad do you have field in the class call cashflow. If yes I think this time refer to that field otherwise this out put can not be.

Comment: @janith1024, there is no such field. I'm sharing my code in github [link](https://github.com/karimiumar/rule-engine). I've have added another Test class ```com.umar.apps.rule.AnonymousLoopTest```. This does not use any database. But the result is same.

Comment: @Mohammad I can not see the com.umar.apps.rule.AnonymousLoopTest class in  link you posted

Comment: The test class is in [AnonymousLoopTest](https://github.com/karimiumar/rule-engine/tree/master/src/test/java/com/umar/apps/rule/)

Comment: Found the issue is with how ```Rule.compareTo()``` is implemented and hence it is only adding the first object to the ```Set``` and returning a ```FALSE``` for subsequent rules that are being added.